# Receiving INVALID_GRANT on authorization_code request for Google Oauth

Tags: google-oauth

We are using OAuth2 to get access to a client's access_token to manage some of their Google Locations.

Our implementation is working fine for most of our clients, but there is a user who is receiving the following response when sending an authorization_code request:
`{  "error": "invalid_grant",  "error_description": "Bad Request"}`

I have seen that there are many reasons why we can receive this for refresh_token requests, but why can we receive this for the initial authorization_code request?

Our authorization server URL: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth

The token server URL: https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token

We have asked the user to try multiple times, by first removing our application from the authorized accounts, but they still receive the invalid_grant response. The issue is also present when another user of the same company wants to authorize us for the same locations.

Edit for additional details:

We are using spring-social for getting the access token from the authorization code (I know that it is EOL, we are only using a small part of it).

Our own code:

```
final OAuth2ConnectionFactory<T> connectionFactory = (OAuth2ConnectionFactory<T>) this.connectionFactoryLocator
                    .getConnectionFactory();
            final String callbackUrl = "...";
// This is the failing call
            final AccessGrant accessGrant = connectionFactory.getOAuthOperations().exchangeForAccess(code, callbackUrl, null);
```

The relevant parts of the library call:

```
    public AccessGrant exchangeForAccess(String authorizationCode, String redirectUri, MultiValueMap<String, String> additionalParameters) {
        MultiValueMap<String, String> params = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
        if (useParametersForClientAuthentication) {
            params.set("client_id", clientId);
            params.set("client_secret", clientSecret);
        }
        params.set("code", authorizationCode);
        params.set("redirect_uri", redirectUri);
        params.set("grant_type", "authorization_code");
        if (additionalParameters != null) {
            params.putAll(additionalParameters);
        }
        return postForAccessGrant(accessTokenUrl, params);
    }

    protected AccessGrant postForAccessGrant(String accessTokenUrl, MultiValueMap<String, String> parameters) {
        Map<String, Object> result = getRestTemplate().postForObject(accessTokenUrl, parameters, Map.class);
        if (result == null) {
            throw new RestClientException("access token endpoint returned empty result");
        }
        return extractAccessGrant(result);
    }
```

The OAuth2Template setup:

```
final OAuth2Template oAuth2Template = new OAuth2Template(config.getClientId(), config.getClientSecret(),
                GoogleOAuthConstants.AUTHORIZATION_SERVER_URL, GoogleOAuthConstants.TOKEN_SERVER_URL);
oAuth2Template.setUseParametersForClientAuthentication(true);
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code.

Comment: Do you have a full error message?   I have an idea what your issue can be I just need to go find it.   This is my list of most obvious causes for [invalid_grant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73527081/1841839)

Comment: This is the entire response: {  "error": "invalid_grant",  "error_description": "Bad Request"}. And we are not talking about refresh_token, but authorization_code grant type (so the initial Oauth2 authorization)

Comment: What type of client credentials are you using?

Comment: bet its the format of LinkedMultiValueMap<String>   The parms should be a http query string applied in the post body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some further investigation, the invalid_grant response was a red herring in our case.

We have some post-processing handled on the same request (loading some data from Google based on that access token), and it seems that if this takes more than ~90 seconds, Google will repeat the callback (with the same authorization_code).

This resulted in us trying to re-use the authorization code - which resulted in the error responses in our logs.

So, the correct answer in our case:
If you are receiving the invalid_grant - Bad Request for an authorization_code request from Google's token servers, then you might be trying to re-use the authorization_code.